# What is the purpose of Lookup operation in ClusterPoint

Tags: database, clusterpoint

I've been trying to use ClusterPoint database for my project, but documentation does not explain how "[Lookup](http://docs.clusterpoint.com/wiki/Lookup)" can be used. It seems there are already methods to [retrieve document by ID](http://docs.clusterpoint.com/wiki/Retrieve) so my question is - How does Lookup differ from Retrieve?

Please explain or point to better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

"Lookup" is more lighter and quicker operation comparing to "Retrieve" as it just looks for document id in index and returns it. However with "Lookup" it's also possible to get selected fields from document by using "list" parameter. In this case "Lookup" becomes very similar to "Retrieve".

Comment: Is there any example for the above?